# correlation plot in ggplot2 with different variables in x and y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, correlation

I want to visualize this correlation matrix using ggplot2. Is it possible to make it like what ggpairs() did but has different variables in x and y axis?

```
round(cor(df_correlation),3)[c(1:5,58,61,66,67,70,71),72:77]

output:
                             Mastery_1 Mastery_2 Mastery_3 Mastery_4 Mastery_5 Mastery_6
Platform_joined                  0.273    -0.049     0.160     0.238     0.324     0.161
gender                           0.223     0.137    -0.076     0.235     0.097    -0.117
native_speaker                  -0.188    -0.511    -0.469    -0.263    -0.238     0.049
English_proficiency             -0.094    -0.411    -0.388    -0.310    -0.221     0.104
SC0                              0.453     0.442     0.391     0.497     0.453     0.261
end_Ask_qs                      -0.200    -0.338    -0.201    -0.226    -0.111     0.112
end_Review_notes                 0.211    -0.183     0.153     0.307     0.412     0.430
end_Study_regularly              0.012    -0.182     0.014     0.123     0.188     0.232
end_Listen_carefully             0.060    -0.590    -0.298    -0.059     0.017     0.211
end_Class_attendance             0.018    -0.143    -0.042    -0.250    -0.233    -0.057
end_Discussion_participation     0.056    -0.119     0.247    -0.076    -0.046     0.382
```

Thank you for any hint!

Comment: `ggpairs` doesn't just show correlation values - it shows scatterplots in the lower triangle, correlation as text in the upper triangle, and density along the diagonal. With the data you have provided, you can only show the corrrlation value as text. Is that what you want?

Comment: @AllanCameron Thank you for your help! I just realize that the ggpairs() is only suitable for the full dataset since the scatter plot and density in the diagonal is focus on one variable... I guess ggcorrplot() is an alternative way if I only focus on the correlation values. Do you know how to apply it on different variables?

Comment: Yes - the ggcorplot look is easily achieved with geom_tile. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You only have correlation values here, which means you can only have the type of `ggpairs` panels with the correlation written on them - the other types such as boxplots and scatter plots require the full data set.

From the comments, it appears you want more of a `ggcorrplot` look:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df_correlation %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  pivot_longer(-1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = rowname, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile() +
  geom_text(aes(label = value)) +
  coord_equal() +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue3", mid = "white", high = "red3") +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL)
```

[image]